# Five9 Outbound script

Tags: javascript, html, css, five9

I am new to Five9. I want to make a Script where there is some Fields where the agents can write some text, and after pressing a button, the text from the Field will go to the List updating the current record. Is there any possibility to realize this without using any CRM or something. Like there is any API request which can do this thing?

Thank you for your help!

```
    <html>
 <head>
 <title> Script  </title>
 
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>

</style>


 </head>
 

 <body>
 <div class="nav_bar">
<button onClick="toggle('target', 'replace_target','replace_target2')">Adatlap</button>
<button onClick="toggle('replace_target', 'target','replace_target2')">Sugo</button>
<button onClick="toggle('replace_target2', 'target', 'replace_target')">Script</button>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span id="target">Test</span>
  <p> This is Test</p>
</div>

<div style="display:none" class="Sugo">
  <span id="replace_target">Test2</span>

</div>
 
<div style="display:none" class="script">
  <span id="replace_target2">SCript</span>
  <p> This is SCript</p>
  <div class="page1">
 </div>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>

 <script>
function toggle(target, source, source2) {
  this[target].parentNode.style.display = 'block'
  this[source].parentNode.style.display = 'none'
  this[source2].parentNode.style.display = 'none'
}
 </script>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Update your post to include code.

Comment: Not too much, I just created an HTML document, with a Text Box where the agent can put the (for eg) the third name of the customer, and I am wondering if I could somehow send the value of this field to the List attached to the campaign, without going to the Interracion tab.

Comment: To help people need code. stack overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @RocketNikita I've added the HTML code, after the Agent puts a value into the <label for="fname">First name:</label> I want to Put that value  into the List.